# WebView - listener when scrolling is done?

Tags: android, webview

`onPageFinished()` (in [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)) is called when the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is done with loading the url, but not with scrolling down ( `WebView.scrollTo()` ).

Is there any way to have a listener when scrolling is done?

Waiting some time like 100ms works mostly, but is a very bad solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure there is anything in the standard WebChromeClient or WebClient interfaces that will let you do that. You will probably need to register a custom javascript object and then use a callback in the page (unless I'm wrong there are DOM level events you can listen for) to notify you when the scroll is done.